# How to add check constraints in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, constraints, sql-server-2014

I want to add the following constraint to the table named `service` in my database.

**Constraint 1:**
Neither `DateCompleted` nor `DueDate` can precede `StartDate`.

```
CREATE TABLE [Service] (
  Service_ID     INT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, Invoice_ID     INT
, Project_ID     INT         NOT NULL
, Description    CHAR(20)    NOT NULL
, Start_Date     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
, Due_Date       VARCHAR(10)
, Planned_Price  VARCHAR(10)
, Actual_Price   VARCHAR(10)
, Status         CHAR(10)    NOT NULL
, Date_Completed VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Another constraint should be added to the table named `client`.

**Constraint 2:**
Column `Post_Code` values should be positive integers with three or four digits.

```
CREATE TABLE [Client] (
  Client_ID      INT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, First_Name     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
, Last_Name      VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
, Street_Address VARCHAR(50)
, Suburb         VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
, State          VARCHAR(3)  NOT NULL
, Post_Code      INT         NOT NULL
, Phone_number   INT         NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Service:

```
ALTER TABLE [Service]
ADD CONSTRAINT [service_datecheck]
CHECK ([StartDate] <= [DateCompleted] AND [StartDate] <= [DueDate]);
```

Client:

```
ALTER TABLE [Client]
ADD CONSTRAINT [client_postcodecheck]
CHECK ([Post_Code] > 0 AND LEN([Post_Code]) IN (3,4));
```

Comment: Might fail on negative.  >=100 <=9999 might be better

Comment: @Paparazzi I did think about doing it that way, and it's probably better, but I opted to match exactly what was in the question.

Comment: works perfectly for my my requirements. Hope you could resolve this too. please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011099/how-to-create-an-sqlserver-functions?noredirect=1#comment63464878_38011099