# HOW to create SQLSERVER functions?

Tags: sql-server

Function 1:

I need to create an sql server function named FirstDayInQtr  to return the first day in the respective quarter of year when a date is input.  This function should be defined with the following header.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FirstDayInQtr(@InputDate datetime) RETURNS datetime AS…
```

Should return the date of first day in the respective quarter. like 1/1/2016

Function 2:

A function to check if an input string consists of UPPERCASE characters.
This function should be defined with the following header.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckStringOfUpperAlphaOK(@String varchar(MAX)) RETURNS varchar(6) AS…
```

Should return "okay" if true and "not okay" if false

Comment: Is it a homework day today? What have you done already? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: run query beginning with`CREATE FUNCTION FirstDayInQtr(@InputDate datetime) RETURNS datetime AS…` ?

Comment: its an assignment, done with create table and check constraints. stuck with functions and stored procedures

Comment: your question is not clear. What can't you do? `create` function or write it's logic?

Comment: need to create two functions.

Comment: one function to check if an input string consists of UPPERCASE characters.  Another function to return the first day of a respective quarter of the year when a date is input

Comment: @Ayyub - for the second function what you want to return?

Comment: it should return the date of the first day of the respective quarter.  like 1/1/2016 if it is the first quarter

Comment: never mind I asked for the second function "CheckStringOfUpperAlphaOK" ...

Comment: "OK" if true, "NOT OKAY" If false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply create function in this way

**Function 1** for getting first day in quarter

```
CREATE FUNCTION FirstDayInQtr(@InputDate datetime) 
RETURNS datetime 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @day datetime

SELECT @day =  DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq ,0, @InputDate),0)

Return @day

END
```

**Function2** For checking capital character as

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckStringOfUpperAlphaOK(@String varchar(MAX))
Returns VarChar(6)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^ ][A-Z]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues collate Latin1_General_Bin, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues collate Latin1_General_Bin, @Temp) + 1, 0, ' ')

    Return @Temp
End
```

Comment: Shows this error .    Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure FirstDayInQtr, Line 9
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: @Ayyub: In case if you want the output in this format `mm/dd/yyyy`, try `DECLARE @day VARCHAR(10); SELECT @day =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, @InputDate), 0), 101); Return  @day;`

Comment: @Nazirullah. Date function works perfectly. Jazzakumullahu khairan.....  Shows following error for Uppercase function. Must declare the scalar variable "@Temp".   The return values for this should be "OKAY" if true and "NOT OKAY" if false.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the First Day of the Current Quater.  I think thats what you are after

```
CREATE FUNCTION FirstDayInQtr(@InputDate DATETIME)

RETURNS DATETIME
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @firstDayOfCurrentQuater DATETIME
    SELECT @firstDayOfCurrentQuater = DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq ,0, @InputDate),0)

    RETURN @firstDayOfCurrentQuater;
END
```